# python - two logger objects with different levels and output streams

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Programming language : Python 3.7

I'd like to set up two Python logger objects: one outputs to a file and another to `sys.stdout`.

Here's my code:

```py
def get_custom_logger(name: str, debug: bool, fname: str = None) -> logging.Logger:
     level = logging.DEBUG if debug else logging.INFO
     if fname is not None:
        logging.basicConfig(filename=fname, filemode='a+', level=level)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=level, stream=sys.stdout)
    return logging.getLogger(name=name)

def main():
    tlog_info = get_custom_logger(name='Test_Info_Stdout', debug=False)
    tlog_info.info('INFO message')
    tlog_info.debug('DEBUG message - will be recorded iff debug = True')
    print(tlog_info)
    #
    tlog_dbg = get_custom_logger(name='Test_Debug_FileStream', debug=True, fname='test.out')
    tlog_dbg.info('INFO message')
    tlog_dbg.debug('DEBUG message - will be recorded iff debug = True')
    print(tlog_dbg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This doesn't work. It either

- prints *all* log messages to the console, regardless of level (if `tlog_info` is instantiated 1st),
  *or*
- outputs *all* log messages to `test.out`, regardless of level (if `tlog_debug` is instantiated 1st)

I've tried using the `handlers` argument to `basicConfig`:

```py
    loghandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout) if fname is None else logging.FileHandler(fname, mode='a+')
    logging.basicConfig(level=level, stream=sys.stdout, handlers=[loghandler])
```

but I get the same result.

What gives?

And is there a cleaner, more *pythonic* way of doing this?

Note that I want to call `get_custom_logger` from various functions/classes of a larger code; some loggers will record to a file, others to the console.

Comment: From the python documentation on basicConfig: `This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.` Only the first call does something. For the second you need to use another way to config your logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `basicConfig` only once. Check [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bfb5f9a66cc348c9cf25c857ad9910479e587517/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1831) comment.

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
def get_custom_logger(name, debug, fname= None):
    level = logging.DEBUG if debug else logging.INFO

    logger = logging.getLogger(name=name)

    if fname is not None:
        handler = logging.FileHandler(fname)
    else:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

    logger.setLevel(level)
    handler.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

Comment: The recommended way is to use `logging.FileHandler(fname)` instead of open.

Answer (score 0):

One way around is to create a root logger and on the top of it add two loggers.
[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules) you have longer explanation how to do it.